# Indented comment on React code for .md file

Tags: reactjs, comments, gitlab, markdown

I'm writing a little tuts about reactstrap on an .md file.
In some places I need to insert some comments inside code blocks but it's shown as code or simple text. I precise that I'm writing on GitLab.

Example: 

`` const Hero = styled(Container)`
    // your styles
` ``

And

````
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <Table>
                // with 30 table rows
                …
                <tr>...</tr> // row number 23
                …
            </Table>
        )
    }
}
```
````

Please help. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX doesn't support JS or HTML comments format, and doesn't 
have it's own format. However, you can write plain JS using the curly braces, and use JS block comments inside:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                { /* I'm a comment, and won't be rendered */ }
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I precise that I'm writing an .md file and I need the comments to be shown on the code to help people to follow my tut.

Comment: The comments appear in the code, and not rendered. I'm not sure that I understand your problem.

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).